# How do I retrieve nodes with one or another value with XPATH

Tags: javascript, regex, xpath

I have a javascript function that needs to retrieve certain nodes through xpath using document.evaluate, till now I am using something like

```
.//span[contains(@title, 'alerting')] | .//span[contains(@title, 'caution')]
```

But it turn in a very long string when values to match are more. I cannot use [@title = word], because I need to retrieve the elements whose atributes contains some string. I have tried things like

```
.//span[contains(@title, ('alerting'|'caution'))]
```

But it does not retrieve anything.

Can you give me an idea to shorten the first sintax?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a function that creates the string and build the expression programmatically, and not worry about it? Roughly:

```
function spanContains(s) {
    return ".//span[contains(@title, '" + s + "')]";
}

var contains = [spanContains('word1'), spanContains('word2')].join("|");
```

You could also try using `matches` instead of `contains`, although I'm not sure what the JavaScript syntax for that would be, or if it's supported.

Answer (score 1):

XPath should be this way:-

```
.//span[contains(@title, 'alerting') or contains(@title, 'caution')]
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .//span[contains(@title, ('alerting'|'caution'))]
> ```

**This is invalid XPath** -- the union operator `|` can only have arguments that are node-sets -- not strings.

**Use**:

```
.//span[@title
          [contains(.,'alerting')
         or
           contains(.,'caution') 
          ]
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `document.evaluate()`, you could use jquery in which case you could do:

```
$('span').filter(function() { 
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    return title != undefined && title.search(/(alerting|caution)/) != -1;
});
```